# Filtering visible map layers based on multiple conditions

Tags: javascript, comparative-review

I am working on a webapp using OpenLayers. I have written a [filter function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) that I can use to tell whether a given layer is visible.

Since there are a bunch of conditions for a layer to be visible, I condensed them all into a single `switch (true)` block, and I was wondering if it was a good thing, since:

- `switch (boolean)` has obviously only two branches
- I think Java forbids `switch (true)` so it must be really bad somehow
- A `case` "falling through" is most of the time an error (forgot to `break`), so as a rule of thumb we forbid such `case` statements
- The language structure whose purpose is *conditions* is the `if` statement, which can be made shorter (less bytes of code) than the `switch` equivalent

But here I wrote a `switch (true)` version and I think this pattern is powerful since it's really easy to add/remove conditions, keep track of them, describe them, etc. After playing around with this method, I also wrote a version which uses an array of expressions instead of the `switch`.

So now I have three versions of the method. Which one do you think is the best and why?

```js
/*global map */
// Sample usage
var visibleLayers = map.getLayers().getArray().filter(isVisible);
```

---

```js
/*global map */
function isVisible(layer) {
    // Layer is not visible if it is hidden, has no data, or is transparent
    if (!layer || !layer.getVisible() || !layer.getSource() ||
            !layer.getOpacity()) {
        return false;
    }
    // Resolution limits
    var minRes = layer.getMinResolution() || 0;
    var maxRes = layer.getMaxResolution() || Infinity;
    var curRes = map.getView().getResolution();

    // Layer is not visible if the current resolution is too low or high
    if (curRes < minRes || maxRes < curRes) {
        return false;
    }
    // Layer is visible in our app only if its type matches
    if (['WMS', 'Vector'].indexOf(layer.getType()) !== -1) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

---

```js
/*global map */
function isVisible(layer) {
    if (!layer) {
        return false;
    }
    // Resolution limits
    var minRes = layer.getMinResolution() || 0;
    var maxRes = layer.getMaxResolution() || Infinity;
    var curRes = map.getView().getResolution();

    switch (true) {
    // Layer is hidden when any of these is true:
    case !layer.getVisible():  // - is hidden
    case !layer.getSource():   // - has no data
    case !layer.getOpacity():  // - is completely transparent
    case curRes < minRes:      // - too low resolution
    case maxRes < curRes:      // - too high resolution
        return false;
    // Layer is hidden *in our app* if none of these is true:
    case layer.getType() === 'WMS':
    case layer.getType() === 'Vector':
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

---

```js
/*global map */
function isVisible(layer) {
    if (!layer) {
        return false;
    }
    // Resolution limits
    var minRes = layer.getMinResolution() || 0;
    var maxRes = layer.getMaxResolution() || Infinity;
    var curRes = map.getView().getResolution();

    // Layer is hidden when any of these is true:
    var hideOn = [
        !layer.getVisible(),  // - is hidden
        !layer.getSource(),   // - has no data
        !layer.getOpacity(),  // - is completely transparent
        curRes < minRes,      // - too low resolution
        maxRes < curRes,      // - too high resolution
    ];

    // Layer type must match
    var typeMatch = ['WMS', 'Vector'].indexOf(layer.getType()) !== -1;

    return typeMatch && !hideOn.some(Boolean);
}
```

(PS: `layer.getType()` is not an OpenLayers method.)

Comment: I agree that the new title is more appropriate since this is what the method does, but I think the question itself is more generic since it's only about JS coding style, the concept of "map layer" is trivial (though I'm new to this site so I may be wrong about the conventions here)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so here is how I decided (yes we can say a lot of things about 20 little lines):

**Performance**

- The first code (with a few `if`) is probably
  the best, since the `||` operator stops whenever a condition is
  evaluated to `true`.
- The second one (with the big `switch`) is a very lil bit slower,
  since we compute `minRes`, `maxRes` and `curRes` before evaluating
  the first exit conditions where they are unused.
  Otherwise, the `switch` statement stops whenever a truthy `case` is found.
- The third one (with the `Array`) is the most wrong approach if I want
  *speed*. We compute the variables, store the N conditions in an array
  of size N, so they're all evaluated, and then we loop through said array
  (`.some()` method) to tell whether it contains a truthy value.

However, regarding this specific app I'm working on, code legibility
and future features are more important than a few microseconds.

**Legibility**

My problem here is that legibility is kinda subjective.
I follow specific coding style and guidelines, and it's easier for me
to read code which follows these guidelines that code which doesn't.

Sadly, on this project, there are no defined conventions and there's an
interesting diversity of whitespace habits.

- The first code is the most legible for most people coming from C,
  but anyone who would come after me would be very tempted to write nested
  `if`, since there are loads of nested code in the repo.
- The second one is still quite legible for C pals, and honestly
  the individual comments on each condition are nice. Also I believe it is
  less tempting to nest conditions, since we would have to change the
  structure first.
- The last one is the most "eye-candy": it has the advantages of the
  `switch`, while being less heavy (`case`, `break`). However, it is
  trickier: "What on Earth is this `!hideOn.some(Boolean)` thing?
  Damn, I'll have to check the docs."

Actually, reading the doc is nice I think. Learning about `.some()`
does not take long, and it's better if maintainers make sure they
know some of the language before, well, maintaining.

**Extensibility**

Extensibility is also important to me. I know this code will not be
reviewed now, but in a few months someone will probably ask:
"what if we also check *this* and *that*?".

In fact, what's likely to happen is "what if we make these conditions
conditional?", ie, add a parameter somewhere, and if this parameter has
some value, then we'll do some more things. This is an interesting way to
check extensibility. Now I'll insert some code since there's been too much
text.

```js
// First code with ifs; nice but we end up nesting conditions
if (configuration === 'wow') {
    doSomething();
    // Comment both conditions
    if (newCond1 || newCond2) {
        return false;
    }
} // Continue

// Second code with switch; I had higher expectations for you
switch () {
case configuration === 'wow':
    doSomething();
    // Comment both conditions
    if (newCond1 || newCond2) {
        return false;
    }
     // Non-breaking case!!
case ...
}

// Other possibility; we may end up with very long lines,
// or multiline conditions (I limit my lines at 80 chars)
switch () {
case configuration === 'wow':
    doSomething();
    // Non-breaking case!!
case configuration === 'wow' && newCond1:  // Comment condition 1
case configuration === 'wow' && newCond2:  // Comment condition 2
case ...
}

// Last code with Array; free candy
if (configuration === 'wow') {
    doSomething();
    hideOn.concat([
        newCond1,  // Comment condition 1
        newCond2   // Comment condition 2
    ]);
}
```

In this particular situation, I think the last one is the most elegant.
Given it's also the most legible in my opinion, and that I'm clearly biased,
and that I want maintainers to read at least ES5 docs once in a while, my choice has been to use the third versions, with the array of booleans.